# Most recent date with 2 conditions to another sheet

Tags: date, excel-formula

I'm working on data tracker to show the most recent activity date with two conditions

Date ___ State ___ City

8/8 ___ KY ___ Lexington

8/9 ___ KY ___ Lexington

8/9 ___ KY ___ Louisville

8/10 ___ GA ___ Atlanta

8/11 ___ KY ___ Frankfort

On another sheet is the overview, to show the most recent activity date without looking through all the incoming data

So essentially the overview would be pulling if State (Column B) is TRUE, then if City (Column C) is TRUE, then the most recent date is found in Column A and then show on the overview on the next sheet.

Comment: It is not clear what you want accomplished. Can you give expected output and an explanation why?

Comment: What I'm trying to accomplish is creating a Summary sheet, that pulls the most recent activity date from location. Multiple States with Multiple cites. So I need to see the most recent activity date from each without combining City and State in one column to do so (if that makes sense?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to be able to specify a city and state on your Summary sheet, and pull in the newest date associated to those two values.

Activity Sheet:

[image]

Summary Sheet:
[image]

```
=MAXIFS('Activity Sheet'!A2:A6,'Activity Sheet'!B2:B6,Summary!B2,'Activity Sheet'!C2:C6,Summary!A2)
```

Comment: If I wanted to take it one step further and also tracker the user, while still following these same rules, would that be too many conditions? I tried using the same formula to capture that data, but rather than generate the name it just gives a "0"

Comment: MAXIFS only works with numeric values.  If you are trying to return a name you will need to do a lookup.  You can do an INDEX/MATCH with your max date value as the lookup value.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you want the earliest (lowest) date for a given city/state combination? So your results would be on the summary page?

| St(ColA) | City(ColB) | Earliest(ColC) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| KY | Lexington | 8/8 |
| KY | Louisville | 8/9 |

I'd suggest combining `XLOOKUP` with an embedded `MIN` for the date, returning the city, state, and date. To create a unique list of the city and states on the summary page, try:

```sql
SORT(UNIQUE(FILTER(detail_range, detail_range<>"")))
```

to have the list spill and avoid any null values.

Comment: With the activity log changing daily but not for every city and start, I am trying pull the most recent activity date

Comment: Col A is Date Col B State and Col C City.

Comment: This way whenever a new entry comes in, over rides the older date and replaces with the new date

Comment: I’ve updated your formatting. I’d encourage you to learn the basics of Markdown so you can do this yourself in the future. The Stack Overflow editor also has a toolbar that will do much of this for you.